# Why can I do `docker cp`, but can't do `docker ls`?

Tags: docker

If I do

```
$ sudo docker cp c7033ac0fdd2:/home/mydir/myfile.txt .
```

file is copied. But if I do

```
$ sudo docker ls c7033ac0fdd2:/home/mydir/
docker: 'ls' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

How to list directory content then and why it doesn't made with with `ls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a couple of reasonable things (there is a shell and an ls program and the entrypoint for the container is not super tightly locked down)

```
docker exec c7033ac0fdd2 ls /home/mydir
```

As to "why?", there is a limit on how much ought to be built into docker and how much you should do with external programs.

If the assumptions are not valid, then you can export the contents of the container as a tar file and look at that, e.g.

```
docker container export c7033ac0fdd2 | tar vtf - | grep /home/mydir
```